# Error '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character while downloading XML file from a network path

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I am trying to download xml file with having some issue with special character. It load successfully in XmlDocument but get the error while transfer  XslCompiledTransform()

```
                document = New XmlDocument()
                Dim strRecords As String = ''
                Dim btBuffer As Byte() = Nothing
                If File.Exists(strFilePathXml) Then

                    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(strFilePathXml, FileMode.Open, 
                     FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
                    document.Load(fs)

                End If
                create navigator
                navigator = document.CreateNavigator
                load style sheet
                transformer = New XslCompiledTransform()
                If File.Exists(strFilePathXslt) Then
                    transformer.Load(strFilePathXslt)
                End If
                transform XML data
                  output = New StringWriter()
                 output.WriteLine("<meta  charset=""UTF-8"">")
                 output.WriteLine("<style>.number {mso-number-format:0\.00; } </style>")
.                transformer.Transform(navigator, Nothing, output)  Getting Exception here
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Anyone can help here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the solution :- 
 Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(strFilePathXml, Encoding.UTF8)
                    Dim content As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                    streamReader.Close()
                    Dim xmlContent As String = Regex.Replace(content, "&#x0", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
                    document.LoadXml(xmlContent)
                    document.PreserveWhitespace = True
```

Comment: It might get you over the problem, but it doesn't address the root cause. How did the null characters get into the XML, and why do you think it is safe to ignore them?

Comment: Special Characters are coming from source as one of the third party tool is using to praduse the XML

Comment: So you have the classic problem with a bug in third-party software. You either have to persuade them to improve their quality, or you have to abandon them as a poor-quality supplier, or you have to repair the defective goods on arrival.